# pyODBC and Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, utf-16, pyodbc

I'm working with pyODBC communicate with a MS SQL 2005 Express server.
The table to which i'm trying to save the data consists of nvarchar columns.

```
query = u"INSERT INTO tblPersons (name, birthday, gender) VALUES('"
query  = query  + name + u"', '"
query  = query  + birthday + u"', '"
query  = query  + gender + u"')"
cur.execute(query)
```

The variables name, birthrday and gende are read from an Excel file and they are Unicode strings.
When I execute the query and either look at the table with SQL Server Management Studio or execute a query that fetches the data that was just inserted, all the data that was written in a non-English languages turn into question marks. The data that was written in English is preserved and appears in the table in the correct way.
I tried adding `CHARSET=UTF16` to my connection string, but had no luck with that.
I can use `UTF-8` which works fine but as a working convention, I need all the data saved in my DB to be `UTF16`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so stupid.. The problem was with the server (had to change my collation to the language I needed)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It could be something related to the odbc driver that pyodbc is using. If that doesn't support unicode, you will probably have to encode the params yourself, like `name.encode('utf-16')`

Also, you should really, really use query parameters, instead of concatenating the sql string yourself, for example:

```
query = "INSERT INTO tblPersons (name, birthday, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
cur.execute(query, [name, birthday, gender])
```

I doubt that this will help with your unicode trouble, but it is a lot safer, and easier.

(and another unrelated tip: using pyodbc via sqlalchemy is a lot nicer, even if you use it just for simple queries and do not use the object-relational mapping stuff)